# What is a good approach for building an aggregated newsletter?

Tags: emails, cron

I would like to auto create a an aggregated newsletter each month based on Craft content and have [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) deliver it via their API. It doesn't need to be complicated so I was wondering whether a standalone PHP script or custom plugin is the best way to go......or custom API end point and feed content to Mailchimp that way.

I am open to suggestions and previous experiences as what would work effectively.